# A Question related to triangle and centroid .

Tags: geometry, triangles

The following is a geometry question I can't seem to get.
"Consider an acute angle △ABC. Points D, E, F are mid points of sides BC, CA and
AB respectively. G is the centroid of △ABC. Area of △AFG = 14, EC = 15/2. Perpendicular distance of F from BC = 6. Find
$BC^2 − AB^2$ "

Here is the figure that I have drawn -
[image: Drawing]

From EC =15/2 I get AE=15/2 So AC =15 .
But what now? How can I utilize the fact that FK=6 and Area(AFG)=14 in finding $BC^2-AB^2$ ?

Comment: (1) If you know the area of one sub-triangle, then you know the area of the whole triangle. (Centroids are cool like that.) (2) If you know $|FK|$, then you know the length of the altitude from $A$. (3) Then you know $|BC|$.

Comment: @Blue Do you mean Area of AFG = Area of FGB = Area of GBD ... ? If so then area of ABC 14*6=84 . Is that right ? Then altitude from A = 6*2=12 Thus BC = 84/6 = 14 . But how to figure out AB ?

Comment: Correct so far. (To verify the area stuff, consider $\triangle BDG$. Its base is $1/2$ that of $\triangle ABC$. And since $G$ is known to be $1/3$ of the way from $D$ to $A$, we can conclude that the height of $\triangle BDG$ is $1/3$ that of $\triangle ABC$. Therefore,$$|\triangle BDG| = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot |\triangle ABC|$$ The same is true for any of the sub-triangles.) Now, for $|AB|$, let $L$ be the foot of the altitude from $A$; you know $|AL|$, so you can get $|CL|$. Then $|BL|$. Then $|AB|$.

Comment: BTW: I'm thinking that there might be a simpler way to get to $|BC|^2 - |AB|^2$ without actually computing $|BC|$ and $|AB|$ individually. At the moment, however, I'm not seeing it.

Comment: @Blue By Pythagoras theorem , CL=9 , thus BL=14-9=5 . Again by Pythagoras theorem AB=13 thus $BC^2-AB^2$=196-169=27 . Is this correct ? Thanks for the hints.

Comment: @Yes,that is correct.Now you could  answer your own question,for completeness and to change its status as an unanswered question.

Comment: I'm too lazy to verify the numbers. ;)  (Oh, it looks like @rahul isn't so lazy. :) The process is correct. Put your solution into an answer and accept it, so that this question will be removed from the Unanswered queue.

Comment: @Blue It seems I can't accept my own answer ( It is saying "You can accept your own answer in two days " )

Comment: So, wait two days. :)  Maybe someone will find the simpler solution by then.

Comment: @Blue,if we could know that angle ACB is acute,we could have used AB^2-BC^2=AC^2-2*BC*CL,but that is not a very efficient way.

Comment: @rahul it is given that angle ACB is acute !

Comment: @Well,you could then try using this formula.And thinking about it again,it really isn't that inefficient.

Comment: @rahul: I had the same thought initially, but that's effectively the Law of Cosines, and OP may not be familiar with (or ready for) it.

Comment: @Blue,but it was confirmed by the OP that the original question mentioned angle ACB being acute.It does not make much sense to mention that unless we are gonna be using it in our calculations.Of course,maybe it was mentioned for the benefit of drawing a proper figure.Nevertheless,your method is  better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note : I got some amazing hints from Blue ( see comments on question ) and only because of them I could solve the problem . I'm answering my own question here but I'll be very grateful if someone else posted a simpler way to compute the answer .

Consider triangles AFG and BFG . They have equal bases ( AF=BF , since F is midpoint. ) They also have equal corresponding heights ( Since they have a common vertex at G ) . So their areas are equal. Similarly areas of all the sub-triangles ( BGD , CGD ...) are equal. Thus they all have area of 14 . So the area of whole triangle ABC = 6 *14 ( since there are 6 sub-triangles ) = 84.

Now draw AL perpendicular to BC . Triangle BFK ~ ( similar ) Triangle BAL . But AB/BF=2 thus AL/FK=2 and AL=2*6=12 . Now Area of triangle ABC = 1/2 * base BC * height AL .
But we already know that area is 84 , thus 84=1/2*BC*12 and BC = 14 .

In triangle ALC , by Pythagoras theorem $CL^2=15^2 - 14^2$ ( Given EC=15/2 thus AC =15 ) .
Thus CL=9. Then BL=BC-CL = 14-9=5 . Now in triangle ABL , by Pythagoras theorem $AB^2 =AL^2+BL^2=12^2+  5^2 $ Thus $AB= 13 $.
Now $BC^2-AB^2=196-169=27 .$

Comment: If we knew that the angle ACB is acute ,we could have used AB^2=AC^2+BC^2-2*BC*CL

Comment: @rahul it is given that ACB is acute ! But how did you figure out that formula ?

Comment: @A Googler,I thought of it instantly after you posted the problem,but I forgot parts of that formula.It says that in any triangle having an acute angle C,as in our case,the above property of triangles hold true..

Comment: @AGoogler (1) I found a typo in your solution - $CL^2=15^2 - 14^2$ should be $CL^2=15^2 - 12^2$ instead. (2) Answering for rah4927, that formula is a derived form of the cosine law.

Comment: @AGoogler Using the same givens, the problem would have been even more interesting if the “finding $BC^2 – AB^2$” part is replaced by “Let C be an external point tangent to the circle (centered at B, radius = BA). Find the location of the point of contact.”